my mesh bend weardly when i move a bone
i'm pretty new in blender, only starting a week ago and when i try to move my mesh with the bone i gave it the mesh start doing weird thing like the arm extending or the body slice in two, i've taken some screen for exemples.
do you have any ideas of how i can fix it ?


Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Hello, LSK, without a share, this is very hard to answer..
